# Amazon EC2 signon asks remote developer for credit card

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I've provided a remote developer with Amazon EC2 signon information. But, when he tries to access amazon ec2, it prompts him for a credit card, as if he's setting up a new account. What URL should I give him so he can enter the signon credentials instead of the getting the new account creation wizard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to: [IAM Home](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?region=us-east-1)

You will find the link there. Send that to the user.
[image]